# Calculate an expression stored inside a string variable in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a conditional expression stored inside a string variable,

For example :

```
declare @x int=501,@y int=0,@str varchar(max)

set @str='if @x > 500 set @y=1000 else set @y=500'
```

Can anybody anybody tell me how can I calculate this string and get the result in `SQL Server 2008` from inside a stored procedure.

Thanks in advance

SD

Answer (score 1):

You need sp_executesql, but it has some nuances especially with passing variables in and getting values out.

```
declare @x int=501,@y int=0,@str Nvarchar(max)
set @str='if @x > 500 set @y=1000 else set @y=500'

exec sp_executesql @str, N'@x int, @y int output', @x, @y output
select @y

-- result
1000
```

Note that @str has been redefined as NVARCHAR. sp_executesql expects the query to be NVARCHAR.
2nd thing to note is that the `output` clause has to be used twice for any variable that needs to keep the value changed inside the `sp_executesql` call

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use dynamic SQL using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Using sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Although, I would examine why you need to do this...]

Comment: Mine too. I suspect vandalism